# Why some websites doesnt open with WWW but they open with WWW

Tags: http, web

Why some websites doesnt open without WWW but some open with WWW like https://developer.apple.com https://developer.mastercard.com

Few reasons i read are like [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/208816/what-is-it-called-when-a-website-url-replaces-www-with-something-else-and-what) states that all traffic is routed though their primary website, does it mean there is no way to access a website through their [www.something.website.com](http://www.something.website.com) form?

Comment: Technically, `www` is just a subdomain as any other (in your example, `developer`). Some webmasters decide to redirect all traffic from `www.example.com` to `example.com` or vice versa, some go for one option exclusively, letting the user end up on an error page if they try to use the other. Since in `developer.apple.com`, `developer` is the subdomain, it replaces the `www`. A common scheme employed by site owners is to use `www` for the regular web content and other subdomains, like `mail`, for other services.

Comment: This question is answered all over the web for decades and is off-topic here. It's also answered on the more on-topic webmasters.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Rob There are still people like me who live somewhere in the world and are just new to stackoverflow. Being a critic is easy than answering question atleast by redirecting. Sure i will check webmasters as you suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*www* is a subdomain

For any website to open with *www* the website owner / domain owner has to configure it so with the domain name service (DNS) provider.

As it is a very common and traditionally used subdomain most websites have it configured. But it is not compulsory to have *www* as the subdomain. Websites can function just normal without it.